# Crash linking to a webpage Android Dev startActivity(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, hyperlink, crash

Crash when linking to a web page from a fragment DialogFragment with the following code

```
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener MoreInfoListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    private String url = "http://penny.hpp.io/?p=63";

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        if (checkConnectivity()){
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(url));
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        } 
    }
```

The Error associated with the crash is as follows:

```
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.PenelopeMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3028)
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3074)
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:143)
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1268)
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.camera.Pcamera.stop(Pcamera.java:137)
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.PenelopeMainActivity.onStop(PenelopeMainActivity.java:522)
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1219)
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5317)
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3025)
12-03 14:26:09.660: E/AndroidRuntime(17567):    ... 11 more
```

I can't figure this one out. Please help. It opens the link but the app crashes in the background. So that when hitting the back button it does not return to the app as usual.

Comment: In class Pcamera in the stop() method something at line 137 is null. It says right in your stacktrace that you posted. If you want us to figure out why something is null you'll need to post the code from that method.

Comment: thanks, must have missed the "caused by" line ...